# RESTful. Какой из методов GET или POST должен использоваться для сервиса подсчета слов в предложении?

Tags: http, архитектура, веб-служба, rest

### Техническое задание

Согласно техническому заданию, необходимо разработать веб-сервис, который на вход получает `JSON-файл` следующего формата

```
{
  "Sentence": "Сегодня 14 октября 2017 год. И да - это осень",
  "Lengths" : [3, 7]
}
```

затем считает количество слов в предложении (`Sentence`) у которых длина слов равна 3 и 7 (`Lengths : [3, 7]`) и возвращает тоже `JSON-файл` в формате

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "Length" : 3,
      "Count"  : 2,
    },
    {
      "Length" : 7,
      "Count"  : 2,
    }
  ]
}
```

Данный сервис хочется построить с учетом `RESTful`. Не могу разобрать какой из методов `GET` или `POST` должен использоватьcя.

---

### Мои мысли по этому поводу

В пользу `GET` мне кажется говорит, то что я ведь должен что-то *получить*. Но мне необходимо отправить `JSON-файл` в теле запроса. А тело ведь в `GET` не используется (теоретически согласно `RESTfull`).

В пользу `POST` говорит то, что я могу использовать *тело запроса*, но ведь `POST` подразумевает создание новой сущности на стороне сервера. А у меня ничего не создается.

Но тем не менее я думаю, что должно это выглядеть так:

```
GET: /api/wordsCounter
Body: 
{
  "Sentence": "Сегодня 14 октября 2017 года. И да - это осень",
  "Lengths" : [3, 7]
}
```

Т.е. *ресурс* - это у меня wordsCounter "СчитывательСлов", использую метод *GET*, где тело сообщения *используется*.

---

### Вопрос

Коллеги, данное решение предлагаю на ваш суд и хочу услышать критику, а именно **какой метод `HTTP` используется при проектировании `Action-сервисов`?** К примеру  `translate.google.ru` использует (если я правильно понял) метод `GET`, когда делает перевод.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest

Comment: @Visman, так все таки `POST`. Может Google не RESTfull придерживается или есть исключения когда необязательно `POST` генерирует создание новой сущности?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/265845/

Comment: @Visman, статья была полезной. Спасибо. Но что ты имел ввиду, отправляя на нее _сильно не заморачивайся при выборе между GET и POST_ или _посмотри лучше в сторону JSON-pure API_?